# CSS position bottom keeping in flow

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a footer-type block that will sit at the bottom of a block, but which will collide with elements at the top of the block when resized.

With a table, this would be easy:

```
<table style="height: 100%;" border="1">
    <!-- border so you can see how it resizes -->
    <tr id="TOP" style="height: 3em;"><td>TOP</td></tr>
    <tr id="GAP"><td>GAP</td></tr>
    <!-- content only so you can see what's going on;
         I want this to render as empty space -->
    <tr id="BOTTOM" style="height: 3em;"><td>BOTTOM</td></tr>
</table>
```

but I'd like to do this without using tables.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.cssstickyfooter.com seems to have an answer:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="header">
    </div>
    <div id="main">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
</div>


html, body { height: 100%; }

#wrap { min-height: 100%; }

#main {
    overflow:auto;
    padding-bottom: 150px;  /* must be same height as the footer */
}

#footer {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -150px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 150px;
    clear:both;
}
```